# Trying to insert into table after rising the application error but its rollbacks

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I am trying to make a Trigger to restrict the user to performing DDL on Saturday and Sunday but if someone tries to insert data it will save that that in the `weekend_action` table but also raise application error that cannot perform DDL.

SQL QUERY:

```
create or replace trigger tgr_wkd_action
before insert
on tbl_39_dept_k 
for each row
declare
begin
  IF trim(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'Day')) IN ('Tuesday', 'Sunday') then 
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'you cannot perform DDL on Weekend');
  end if;
  
  if inserting then
     insert into user_admin.weekend_actions values 
       (:NEW.Dept_no,
        'updation',
        'user'||user||'trying to insert data on'||'_'||sysdate||'from Table tbl_39_dept_k');
  end if;
end tgr_wkd_action;
```

Comment: Your code is `IF tue/sun THEN raise error ELSE log error`. Is this what you want? Or do you want to write the log entry only on tue/sun rather than not on tue/sun? Or even regardless of the day? Remember that `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` quits the script; once you raise an error, you will not each the lines that follow.

Comment: no no, i just put that because I was checking it ...today is Tuesday that's why

Comment: i want to raise the application error and also get a log entry

Comment: Then move your insert statement before the raise statement.

Comment: no its dosent work even if i move it before raise statement because raise statement rollbacks

Answer (score 2):

> if someone tries to **insert** data

Exactly. Insert.

Your trigger fires before **update**, and that's a different DML.

---

Apart from that:

- inserts and updates are DML (data manipulation). DDL you mentioned is data **definition** (these are create table, alter table, ...)
- weekend action vs. **Tuesday**? Since when is Tuesday *weekend*?

---

Perhaps you meant

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tgr_wkd_action
  2     BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  3     ON tbl_39_dept_k
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  DECLARE
  6  BEGIN
  7     IF TRIM (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'Day', 'nls_date_language = english')) IN
  8           ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
  9     THEN
 10        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'you cannot perform DML on Weekend');
 11     END IF;
 12
 13     IF INSERTING
 14     THEN
 15        INSERT INTO weekend_actions
 16                VALUES (
 17                          :NEW.Dept_no,
 18                          'inserting',
 19                             'user'
 20                          || USER
 21                          || 'trying to insert data on'
 22                          || '_'
 23                          || SYSDATE
 24                          || 'from Table tbl_39_dept_k');
 25     ELSIF UPDATING
 26     THEN
 27        INSERT INTO weekend_actions
 28                VALUES (
 29                          :NEW.Dept_no,
 30                          'updating',
 31                             'user'
 32                          || USER
 33                          || 'trying to update data on'
 34                          || '_'
 35                          || SYSDATE
 36                          || 'from Table tbl_39_dept_k');
 37     END IF;
 38  END tgr_wkd_action;
 39  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO tbl_39_dept_k (dept_no) VALUES (10);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Tables' contents:

```
SQL> select * from tbl_39_dept_k;

   DEPT_NO
----------
        10

SQL> select * from weekend_actions;

   DEPT_NO ACTION     MSG
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        10 inserting  userSCOTTtrying to insert data on_23.11.21from Table tbl_39_dept_k

SQL>
```

---

Pretending it is weekend today (while it is Tuesday):

```
<snip>
  7     IF TRIM (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'Day', 'nls_date_language = english')) IN
  8           ('Tuesday', 'Sunday')
  9     THEN
<snip>
 39  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO tbl_39_dept_k (dept_no) VALUES (20);
INSERT INTO tbl_39_dept_k (dept_no) VALUES (20)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: you cannot perform DML on Weekend
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TGR_WKD_ACTION", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TGR_WKD_ACTION'


SQL>
```

Comment: is it only going to raise an error or also insert into the log table

Comment: your code is ok but I still have the same problem it's raising the error but it not inserting the value in the log table

Comment: Right; my code is OK. I suggest you adjust YOUR code so that it works just as my does.

Comment: no u code is ok but it's not doing what my problem was ..actually, my code also works fine dose the same thing ... I want the trigger to show exception and also insertion at the same time on Saturday...what your code dose it only shows exception but doesn't do insertion

Comment: You can't raise an exception AND let the row be inserted. If you raise and exception, than that's it - no further processing is allowed (therefore, no insert will ever happen).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67217183/trying-to-insert-into-a-table-after-a-raise-application-error-on-oracle-doesnt

Comment: someone showed in this link  how to do it but idk how to di it form my tables

Comment: That (an autonomous transaction procedure) is used for logging purposes.